# Failed to load image error code 2

Tags: c++, image, runtime-error

i am fairly new to programming in general and i am having trouble understanding the code given to me as part of my assignment.

I am trying to draw a bitmap in the program using this code

```
void Sprite::Draw(Canvas & c)
{
    draw_impl(c);
        c.DrawBitmap(50, 50, 50, 50, "H:\UserData\Desktop\ArcadeGame\ArcadeGame\Images\circle.bmp", 255, 0, 0);

}
```

I have now changed it so i am using the full path instead of a relative path. However the error is still present.

```
void WinCanvas::DrawBitmap(int x, int y, int w, int h, std::string filename, int r, int g, int b)
{
    std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(filename.begin(), filename.end());    // convert to wide string

    HBITMAP  hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, stemp.c_str(), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);
    if( hBmp == NULL )
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
            std::wstring errorMsg = L"Failed to LoadImage - '" + stemp + L"', error code (" + std::to_wstring((long long)err) + L")";
        MessageBox(NULL, errorMsg.c_str(), L"WinCanvas::DrawBitmap()", MB_OK);

        PostMessage(m_hWnd, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL);    // Post a message to destroy (shutdown) the program
        return;
        .
    }
```

I am not sure if there is something wrong with my image location source or if i did not draw my bitmap properly using the proper integers.

Below is the declaration of the integers used

```
virtual void DrawBitmap(int x, int y, int w, int h, std::string filename, int r=0, int g=0, int b=0);
```

Thank you guys for all your help. I changed the code to

```
c.DrawBitmap(50, 50, 50, 50, "H:\\UserData\\Desktop\\ArcadeGame\\ArcadeGame\\Images\\circle.bmp", 255, 0, 0);
```

However, it is now coming up with error code 0 instead of 2. If i am reading it correctly, the error message is saying failed to load characters of string.

Comment: You're using a relative path, so the error is probably that your current dir isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 2: `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. 2 (0x2). The system cannot find the file specified.`

- Make sure file exists
- Use double slash in you path string, otherwise you're escaping the next char, something like:
  "H:\\UserData\\Desktop\\ArcadeGame\\ArcadeGame\\Images\\circle.bmp"